# multiple matrices allocation in fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation

Suppose during the execution of a program you get the following output file:

1  2

2  2

3  1

.

.

.

n 5

and the first line tells you that you need a matrix say `A(2,k)`, the second line a matrix `B(2,k)`, the third line a matrix `C(1,k)`,..., and the last line a matrix `S(5,k)`, where n and k are already known.

How do you allocate the matrices `A,B,C`,...,`S`? If the entries of second column of the file where the same e.g 5, I could allocate one matrix, i.e:

```
real, allocatable :: mymat(:,:,:)
```

and after reading the output file I would allocate:

```
allocate(mymat(n,5,k))
```

and that would be the end of the story. In this case, I can't do that, since the second dimension varies, so I need `n` different matrices. Any ideas?

Comment: An array of a derived type containing an allocatable component would be one way forward. Will write an example later if I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the last line means a `S(5,k)` matrix, not `S(n,k)` as you wrote?

Assuming you know the maximum value in the second column, say `smax`, your solution `real, allocatable :: mymat(:,:,:)` then `allocate(mymat(n,smax,k))` is perfectly acceptable if you accept occupying more memory than needed. The first submatrix will be `mymat(1,1:2,:)`, the second submatrix will be `mymat(2,2:2,:)`, the third one `maymat(3,1:1,:)`, and so on... Note that it would be better to assign the matrix number to the 3rd dimension so that each submatrix is contiguous in memory, i.e. `allocate(mymat(smax,k,n))`

Otherwise, as suggested by @IanBush, you may define a derived type:

```
type array_t
    real, allocatable :: a(:,:)
end type

type(array_t) :: mymat(:)

allocate( mymat(n) )

allocate( mymat(1)%a(2,k) )
allocate( mymat(2)%a(2,k) )
allocate( mymat(3)%a(1,k) )
...
```

(of course the individual allocates would be in a loop)